# Running standalone Glassfish v3 client as Eclipse plugin

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, client, glassfish-3

I'm developing a standalone client that invokes some EJB methods on Glassfish v3. This works well until I'm integrating the client into an Eclipse plugin for running in our RCP application. In this setting there seems to be a classloader problem on initializing the naming context and I get the exception listed below. (The client has gf-client.jar and all its dependencies on its classpath.)

It fails on

```
m_ctx = new InitialContext();
```

with the exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findResources(java.lang.String)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1605)
            at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.ManifestProxy.<init>(ManifestProxy.java:34)
            at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.ProxyModuleDefinition.<init>(ProxyModuleDefinition.java:78)
            at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.ProxyModuleDefinition.<init>(ProxyModuleDefinition.java:73)
            at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.SingleModulesRegistry.<init>(SingleModulesRegistry.java:42)
            at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.SingleModulesRegistry.<init>(SingleModulesRegistry.java:30)
            at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.<init>(StaticModulesRegistry.java:60)
            at org.glassfish.internal.api.Globals.getStaticHabitat(Globals.java:67)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.<init>(SerialContext.java:183)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.<init>(SerialContext.java:253)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory.createInitialContext(SerialInitContextFactory.java:121)
            at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory.getInitialContext(SerialInitContextFactory.java:116)
            at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
            at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:175)
```

Has anybody an idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I am encountering the same error when trying to initialize an embedded Glassfish container in JUnit (via Ant and NetBeans).

Answer (score 2):

Further investigation of the Problem has shown, that Glassfishv3 relies on a public method `findResources(java.lang.String)` of the `java.lang.Classloader`.

```
package com.sun.enterprise.module.single;
[...]
public class ManifestProxy extends Manifest {
    [...]    
    public ManifestProxy(ClassLoader cl, List<SeparatorMappings> mappings) throws IOException {
        try {
           [...]
            Method met = cl.getClass().getMethod("findResources", String.class);
            Enumeration<URL> urls=null;
            try {
                met.setAccessible(true);
                urls = (Enumeration<URL>) met.invoke(cl, JarFile.MANIFEST_NAME);
```

But this method is protected in the Classloader class itself. When running the client as standalone java application the derived classloader `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader` is used which overrides this method and declares it public.
But when running as Eclipse plugin the classloader `org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader` does not override the `findResource`-Method which leaves it protected and inaccessible by the ManifestProxy class.

What is the best way to solve this? How can I set a specific classloader for a eclipse plugin/osgi bundle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you using proper context settings?

```
    1. Properties props=new Properties();  
   2. props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");  
   3. props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");  
   4. props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort","3700");
```

Comment: Yes, the properties are set correctly. My client works perfectly when running it as standalone java application. Just in the eclipse plugin context the classloader problem occurs.